# Error adding bootstrap 5 toaster to angular 17 as standalone components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, angular17, angular-standalone-components

I am trying to add a [bootstrap toaster](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/toast/overview) to my angular project. I am using angular 17 with standalone components.

I am trying to follow what was done in [this github](https://github.com/svierk/angular-bootstrap-toast-service/blob/main/src/app/services/toast.service.ts) repository but my project is standalone.

Running `ng serve` is successful but when I am trying to access `http://localhost:4200/` I get the following error

```
[vite] Internal server error: document is not defined
      at enableDismissTrigger (D:\dev\git-2.0\base-templates\angular\angular-bootstrap-5-base\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.esm.js:802:19)
      at eval (D:\dev\git-2.0\base-templates\angular\angular-bootstrap-5-base\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.esm.js:884:1)
      at async instantiateModule (file:///D:/dev/git-2.0/base-templates/angular/angular-bootstrap-5-base/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-G-px366b.js:54758:9) (x6)
```

[https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Chrispie/code-problems](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/Chrispie/code-problems) on my `issue-creating-bootstrap-5-toaster-with-angular-17-standalone` branch:
[image]

I added my sample project where I have reproduced the error to my [github repo](https://github.com/Chrispie/code-problems/tree/issue-creating-bootstrap-5-toaster-with-angular-17-standalone).

Any idea as to what am I doing wrong here or what does it mean in this context?

For completeness sake I am outlining below what I have done.

I created a new angular project with scss and added the following 2 dependencies

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i @types/bootstrap --save-dev
```

A toast and a toaster component is added with a service and 2 models. The main app component has a few buttons to launch the toasts.

When running I am expecting it to look something like this

[image]

Comment: You should really place the code on https://stackblitz.com instead of github when asking questions

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn 100% correct. I added a link. Not 100% sure if my branch can be embedded in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [Server side rendering (SSR)](https://angular.io/guide/ssr) with bootstrap does not work hand in hand. Not sure if there are a way to still use it with SSR.

But for now I disabled SSR by following the steps on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/1apc511/how_can_i_turn_off_ssr_in_angular_17/) site:

- Rm main.server.ts
- Rm server.ts
- Rm src/app/app.config.server.ts
- Remove these keys from architect in angular.json
- "server": "src/main.server.ts", "prerender": false, "ssr": { ... }
- Remove these from tsconfig.app.json

  - files -> "src/main.server.ts"
  - types: [ "node" ] becomes "types": []
- npm uninstall @angular/ssr express @angular/platform-server
- npm uninstall -D @types/express @types/node

I uploaded the solution to another branch called [issue-creating-bootstrap-5-toaster-with-angular-17-standalone-resolved](https://github.com/Chrispie/code-problems/tree/issue-creating-bootstrap-5-toaster-with-angular-17-standalone-resolved) if it might help anyone.